# How to improve/speed up SQL query

Tags: sql, query-optimization, informix

I have a query that works, but takes an incredibly long time to run.  Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Essentially I want to grab all rows where the location is 106, the purchase_date >= today - 300, the assigned_worker includes Alex or Carol.  This produces rows with the same cost_id.  I only want one row for each cost_id and would like that row to be the one with the highest cost_num.

```
select distinct t.cost_id, t.column_a, t.column_b
from mytable t
where  t.location in (106) and t.purchase_date >= today - 300  and (t.assigned_worker like '%Alex%' or d.assigned_worker like '%Carol%' )
and t.cost_num in (select max(cost_num) from mytable where cost_id = t.cost_id
and location in (106));
```

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana is there a particular piece of the data you want more info on? I can provide samples it will just take quite a bit of time to create fake data

Comment: just enough information to visualize the problem and understand the logic better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to find the root cause of slowness without knowledge of indexes and explain plan (and - in my personal case - Informix). Few (caution - may be misleading!) ideas:

- replace `t.location in (106)` by `t.location = 106`
- create index on `location` or `purchase_date` or `cost_id`
- avoid `like '%...'` if possible
- avoid `or` - replace by `union`
- replace subselect by window function if Informix supports it (extract rows with `row_number() over (partition by location, cost_id order by cost_num desc)` equals to 1)
- alias table and column in subselect, at least for readability

Comment: All these are reasonable suggestions. Looking at the output from SET EXPLAIN would perhaps be informative, but we would need the schema of the table (singular — there is only one) with information about indexes, row size, cardinality, etc too.